# "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test" does not work in PSQL, trying to connect PSQL to VSCode

Tags: postgresql, ssl, visual-studio-code, psql

I am trying to connect my PSQL to VSCode and I am getting an error saying "The server does not support SSL Connections", while looking for the solution in stackoverflow I found a suggestion to run

`psql "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"`

When I try that from within PSQL Shell (12.3) for windows, it gives me this error:

```
   postgres=# sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test;
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "sslmode"
    LINE 1: sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test;
```

When I try from the command prompt it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\cu>Psql -U postgres  "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"
Password for user postgres:
Psql (12.3)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

test=# Psql -U postgres  "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"
test-# ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Psql"
LINE 1: Psql -U postgres  "sslmode=allow host=localhost dbname=test"
```

Can you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong, I am new to databases and any type of programming and I am trying to learn some SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you connect via psql, you are already connected to the database.  You can't then use a connection string on the psql prompt.

In your example output, you are trying to call psql once you're in psql.  That command can only be run on the command line, outside of psql.

You appear to have it running correctly at the top of your example, so there is no need to run it again once you have the psql prompt up.

As for the error about the server not supporting SSL connections, you will need to set `ssl` to `on` in your `postgresql.conf` file and restart the database.  You will probably find that is currently set to `off`.

If you're reading the `WARNING` output as an error, it isn't. It's just saying that the character set of the console that you're using doesn't match the server, and then directs you to the documentation.  Look up the section "Notes for Windows users" on the psql page in the documentation for more information: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html

Comment: Hi Thom, thank you for your detailed explanation. The solution of editing the PostgreSQL.conf file worked, and now I have VSCode connected to Postgres.  In case anyone else runs into this problem: I located the PostgreSQL.conf file using `postgres=# SHOW config_file;` opened the file with a text editor and searched for SSL, as anticipated by Thom it was set to `off` so I just changed it to `on` and problem solved. Once again, thank you so much for your help!